# Statsmodel SMF Limit of variables

Tags: statsmodels

Does statsmodels smf formula have a limit of variables?
I get a NAN in the adjusted R² with 14 columns. With 13 columns I have values.
I tried different combinations and it is not dependent which column is exlcuded.

```
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
results = smf.ols('Pax~Col1+Col2+....Col14', data=RuAr).fit()

OLS Regression Results Dep. Variable:   Pax     R-squared:  1.000
Model:  OLS     Adj. R-squared:     nan
Method:     Least Squares   F-statistic:    0.000
Date:   Tue, 10 Mar 2020    Prob (F-statistic):     nan

coef    std err     t   P>|t|   [0.025  0.975]
Intercept   -8.066e+06  inf     -0  nan     nan     nan
Col1    1.166e+06   inf     0   nan     nan     nan
```

Comment: There is no limit on the number of variables, only limitation is computer memory. Most likely you have perfect collinearity, perfect prediction or some other problems with your data. With perfect prediction, the estimated error variance is zero, with numerical noise it could be negative which can create follow-up problems, e.g. when taking sqrt.

Comment: Yes that is the problem. Thank you.